# Looping through array ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a set of numbers `123456789`

I am writing a loop, so for every 3 numbers/characters it insert a comma, and then starts a new line.

What type of loop would I use for this?  And how do I tell ruby for every 3 numbers?  `"123456.each_char.limit(3)"`?  I I know limit isnt correct but hopefully im getting the idea accross.

Comment: is the set of numbers in an array or is it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts 123456789.to_s.gsub(/(.{3})/,"\\1,\n")
```

result :

```
123,
456,
789,
```

alternative loop way :

```
"123456789".each_char.with_index(1) do |item, index|
    if index % 3 == 0
        print item + ",\n"
    else
        print item
    end          
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the set of numbers is a string you can use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to split up the characters into groups of 3 and then join them together before printing to the console:

```
[21] pry(main)> "123456789".chars.each_slice(3) { |a| p "#{a.join}," }
"123,"
"456,"
"789,"
```